# Why in MISO, SISO, MIMO definition Input is Transmitting antennas not the receiving ones?

Tags: lte, 5g

This is a definition for SIMO in the reference below:

"The SIMO or Single Input Multiple Output version of MIMO occurs where the transmitter has a single antenna and the receiver has multiple antennas."

As I understand when transmitting a signal, power will go from transmitting antennas to receiving one. So should the Transmitting antenna be the Output instead of Input in the SIMO definition?

https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/antennas-propagation/mimo/siso-simo-miso-mimo.php

Comment: You don't look at it from the perspective of the radio waves coming in and out of the antennas. You look at it from the perspective where you are injecting electrical signals (data) into the system and where you are outputting electrical signals from the system since the electrical signals are what you are working with. The system is the transmitter and receiver all balled up together.

Comment: I had always read it as with respect to the RF channel, which is the interesting and complex thing that's being coerced into carrying multiple data streams. If you add its physical layer interfaces, it becomes what @DKNguyen said.

Comment: @Neil_UK That works too. Make up whatever you need for the definition to make sense lol.

Comment: Thank you @DKNguyen and Neil_UK. I also found this [application note](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-02324/application-notes/5990-4760.pdf) from Keysight and it explained well as you did. So Tx feeds the data into radio channel (medium) so it is an Input. Then Rx receives the signal, sends it to the system, and become the Output. Tx (IN) > Blackbox (medium) > Rx (OUT)